# How can I get a user password using the Auth0 Management API nuget package?

Tags: auth0

We are currently trying to make a change to our website so that it uses Auth0 to authenticate. As part of that, I am rewriting a "config" website that we have for managing the users. The users will now be stored in Auth0 and the config website will therefore have to be able to add and edit Auth0 users in my tenant.

The config website uses the Auth0 Management API nuget package: https://github.com/auth0/auth0.net

But I have run into a problem. I can get a list of users and I can create a user. I can get the user's details and present them in an edit form onscreen, but I can't save the changes made, because when I try to do this I get an error that I need to supply a password in the UserUpdateRequest.

But when I get the user's details (client.Users.GetAsync(id)), it doesn't give me back a password property. If I could get the password from the call to GetAsync(id) then I could add it to the UserUpdateRequest. But if I can't get the password from GetAsync, how can I put the password in the UserUpdateRequest? How am I supposed to ever save a user?

**I guess my ultimate question is: how can I get the user's password using the Management API...so that I can supply it later on to the UserUpdateRequest model when calling Users.UpdateAsync. Or if I can't get the user's password, can I somehow update the user without knowing their password?**

It looks like the Nuget Management API was expecting this method to be used by the user themselves (and they could therefore put in their password to change their details), not an admin user operating through a config/admin website that wouldn't know the users password.

C# User/Edit [HttpGet] action method to get users and display them:

```
var token = GetAccessToken();
var apiClient = new ManagementApiClient(token, new Uri("https://MY_TENANT_ID.au.auth0.com/api/v2"));
var user = await apiClient.Users.GetAsync(id);
var userModel = MapUserToUserModel(user);
return View(userModel);
```

C# User/Edit [HttpPost] action method to save the changes to user's details:

```
var token = GetAccessToken();
var apiClient = new ManagementApiClient(token, new Uri("https://MY_TENANT_ID.au.auth0.com/api/v2"));
var updateReq = new UserUpdateRequest()
{
    UserName = model.UserId,
    Email = model.Email,
    Password = model.Password,
    EmailVerified = model.EmailVerified,
    AppMetadata = model.AppMetadata,
    UserMetadata = model.UserMetadata
};

var user = await apiClient.Users.UpdateAsync(model.UserId, updateReq);
```